# Uploaded images not displaying in network site

Tags: images, uploads, media-library, multisite

I have a network of sites and have recently added another site. When I upload an image it uploads to the correct directory but is showing a broken image link when viewed within the library or on the site. I checked the site's setting and everything looks correct.

file actually uploads to 
blogs.dir\7\files\2011\03\1551-oct-cable.png

broken image link location e.x.
http://apollo.site.net/mainsite/kb/files/2011/03/1551-oct-cable.png

I really have no idea where to go on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed

```
        <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

Also here's a bit more information I was able to find. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/images-files-not-displaying